# Managing multiple users on the same MySQL server

Tags: mysql, web-server, hosting

So, I'm going to be offering a LAMP for myself and a few of my friends.

I want to make it so each user can create databases and delete them, etc. without seeing the other user's databases. I don't want to have to limit the number of databases to 1, and I want them to have full control over "their" databases.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you are looking for,but you (as MySQL root) can create each database and the grant full access to it by issuing:

```
create database_name;
grant all privileges on database_name.* to user_name@connecting_host identified by 'password';
flush privileges;
```

If your user_name already exists, then you can skip the `identified by` part.